# Fruit puree suspended in beer

Tags: fruit

I brewed a saison which I racked onto secondary together with apricot puree. One week down the line I did a measurement and noticed the fruit puree is suspended in the beer. I think I'll wait for another week to dry hop and then another one before bottling.

I was just wondering, will the puree settle down? If not what are my options to keep these bits and pieces out of my beer?

Answer (score 3):

I did a pumpkin beer where I used copious amounts of cooked pumpkin in the secondary. After fermentation subsided, the pumpkin in the secondary was suspended to the point it was more like a smoothie in consistency. I actually did a combination of things to clear the beer; first I racked it into a bucket through a larger strainer (both sanitized). Then I added [liquid isinglass](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0064O9E44) and watched that for a couple of weeks. After which I cold crashed and then kegged. It still had considerable haze but was no longer the smoothie consistency.

Answer (score 1):

It will usually drop out just fine, with just cold crashing.

I've found the fruit puree drops out really well with gelatin and cold crash.

There are particles I've found that really only drop out with a lot of aging. For example long chain proteins from bacteria. Many fruit sours may take over a year to age into something that is clear and peak flavor.  Filtering is another option, but can quickly get pricey as many of the filters are single use and it may take several filters for a single batch.

Answer (score 0):

I have used an industrial centrifuge to clear fruit wines. A rather uncommon piece of equipment but it works rather well.